# One keypress produces more keycodes

Tags: keyboard

I have installed linux (tested debian 9 and linux mint 18) on a older laptop (acer aspire timeline X 5820) and there is a problem with its keyboard.

There are controles of volume and display brightness on its arrows (working when fn key is pressed). Three of them are working fine while the last one (brightness down) is not. **When the key** (the arrow together with fn) **is pressed it initializes both brightness down and change to external monitor**.

The `xev` output is (for one press of the arrow when fn is held):

```
MappingNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248

FocusOut event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x7200001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x7200001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x7200001,
    root 0xb0, subw 0x0, time 5319155, (1023,637), root:(1023,666),
    state 0x10, keycode 235 (keysym 0x1008ff59, XF86Display), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

MappingNotify event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248

FocusOut event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x7200001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 42, synthetic NO, window 0x7200001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 42, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 42, synthetic NO, window 0x7200001,
    root 0xb0, subw 0x0, time 5319238, (1023,637), root:(1023,666),
    state 0x10, keycode 232 (keysym 0x1008ff03, XF86MonBrightnessDown), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The `showkey` output is:

```
keycode 227 press
keycode 227 release
keycode 224 press
keycode 224 release
```

The keyboard has also **dedicated key** (F5 with fn) for the change of the display to be used - this produces **no output** neither in `xev` nor in `showkey`.

Both lowering brightness and display change work, however only at the same time. "Works" the same on both linuxes. It was fine on windows, so it is not hardware problem.

**Is it possible (and how) to transfer the code** `keycode 235 (keysym 0x1008ff59, XF86Display)` to the right key?

Answer (score 0):

Laptops are always tricky, because every manufacturer does something differently, and there's no documentation by the manufacturer, just Windows drivers.

From your description, it looks like in the current mode the [Embedded Controller (EC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_controller) is in, it just produces the wrong sequence for Fn + brightness down, and no sequence or some other kind of event for Fn + F5.

As there's no documentation how to reprogram the EC to do that differently, the best solution I can think of is to map XF86Display to something else (via `xmodmap` etc.) that is ignored and doesn't change the display. In that way, the brightness down key will work correctly, even if producing an additional symbol.

If you can find some other event that's produced for Fn + F5 (e.g. with `acpi_listen`), then you can add some custom stuff to react to that event. If you can't find any event, you'll either have to map that keysym to some other key combination (without Fn), or live with the fact that this key is missing.